# Rectangle / Complex and Float Error / Python

Tags: python-2.7

## Write a python program that prompts the user to enter the center x-, y-coordinates,

width, and height of two rectangles and determines whether the second rectangle is
inside the first or overlaps with the first, or outside the first rectangle (does not overlap)
as shown in the following Figure and the sample run below. Make sure to test your
program to cover all the 3 cases.

## TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'float' and don't know how to fix it.

```
def main():
    Center1X = eval(input("Please enter rectangle #1's center x-coordinate: "))  
    Center1Y = eval(input("Please enter rectangle #1's center y-coordinate: ")) 
    Width1 = eval(input("Please enter rectangle #1's width: ")) 
    Height1 = eval(input("Please enter rectangle #1's height: ")) 
    Center2X = eval (input("Please enter rectangle #2's center x-coordinate: "))  
    Center2Y = eval(input("Please enter rectangle #2's center y-coordinate: ")) 
    Width2 = eval(input("Please enter rectangle #2's width: ")) 
    Height2 =  eval (input("Please enter rectangle #2's height: "))  

    Distance_X1X2 = (Center1X**2 - Center2X**2)**0.5
    Distance_Y1Y2 = (Center2Y**2 - Center2Y**2)**0.5

    DistanceWidth = (Width1/2) + (Width2/2) 
    DistanceHeight = (Height1/2) + (Height2/2) 

    if (Distance_X1X2 > DistanceWidth):
        print ("The Result is : Rectangle2 does not overlap Rectangle1")
    elif (Distance_Y1Y2  > DistanceHeight):
        print ("The Result is : Rectangle2 does not overlap Rectangle1")
    elif Distance_X1X2 < DistanceWidth  and Distance_Y1Y2  < DistanceHeight :
        print("The Result is :Rectangle2 is inside Rectangle1.")
    else:
        print("The Result is :Rectangle2 overlaps Rectangle1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your formula for distance computation is wrong:

```
Distance_X1X2 = (Center1X**2 - Center2X**2)**0.5
```

should be

```
Distance_X1X2 = (Center1X**2 + Center2X**2)**0.5
```

Hence sometimes the `Center1X**2 - Center2X**2` is negative, and the square root of a negative number returns a `complex` number in python, which doesn't compare to `float` because it is bi-dimensional (real,imaginary parts)

With the proper formula, square root is positive: no more complex numbers.

Aside: don't do `eval(input())`, prefer `float(input())`, it's safer (no-one can inject python code in your script)